# jQuery hover over an li that excludes the children of the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a Wordpress-menu with a submenu. I've added an arrow to the `li` element that has a submenu inside. When the mouse goes over the `a` inside the `li` it makes an hover animation with CSS. Now I wanted to extend the animation to the arrow that is inside a `span` element inside the `a` tag. I did it with jQuery,

```jquery
$('nav ul li.menu-item-has-children').hover(function() {
    $('nav ul li a span.arrow').css('color', '#fff');
}, function() {
    $('nav ul li a span.arrow').css('color', '#be1722');
});
```

But when the submenu is opened and the mouse is over it, the arrow remains white. How can avoid this?

This is the structure of my menu:

```html
<nav>
    <li class="menu-item-has-children">
        <a>Menu item with sub menu</a><span class="arrow">arrow</span>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a>Sub menu link</a>
            </li>          
        </ul>
    </li>
</nav>
```

I tried also with this:

```
$('nav ul li.menu-item-has-children a').hover(function() {
    $('nav ul li a span.arrow').css('color', '#fff');
}, function() {
    $('nav ul li a span.arrow').css('color', '#be1722');
});
```

But if I hover an `a` tag in the submenu the function starts again and the arrow turns white.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your element is `<span>arrow</span>`;. But `span.arrow` in `$('nav ul li a span.arrow')` searches for a `<span>` element with a class `.arrow`. And there is no such class assigned to your `<span>` element.

Use this:

```
<span class="arrow">arrow</span>
```

---

The selector `$('nav ul li a span.arrow')` searches for `<span>` inside(child of) `<a>`.

The `span` element is *not the child of `a`* but its sibling, use `+` instead of a space in the selector.

```
$('nav ul li.menu-item-has-children a').hover(function() {
    $('nav ul li a+span.arrow').css('color', '#fff');
}, function() {
    $('nav ul li a+span.arrow').css('color', '#be1722');
});
```

See **[Next adjacent Selector (“prev + next”)](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-selector/)**

Comment: I don't even see `<span>` exists! :)

Comment: @FeliceCaricati if this has helped you please accept the answer.